# Restfull urls for ASP.NET page on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, custom-url

Ok I had a huge Issue giving this a proper title, my excuses for that.

Anyways I have started slowly to look at Web and ASP.NET again, I am a C# developer but I have mostly worked with Windows applications the past 5 years or so, It is not that I haven't touched the web as such in that time, but this is as web services (Restfull as well as the ugly SOAP services) I have also worked with more "raw" web requests.

But I have not worked with IIS or ASP.NET in all that time.

What I would like to do is hos a web page that uses a URL style I could best describe with "like rest", hence the "Restfull urls" title. Because I think most people thinks of such URL's in terms of:

```
http://example.com/item/
http://example.com/item/23/
```

and so forth. Not that they have to look like that, however I would like to use such URL's instead of

```
http://example.com/item?id=23
```

I know subtext does this, but i have not had any luck finding it in their code base.

Now as far as I can tell I could just implement some IHttpHandler's, but at least for the examples I have seen of that, they write the page source back in code, and I still have master pages etc. I wish to use instead of taking over all that stuff my self, I really just kinda wants to route http://example.com/item/23/ to http://example.com/item and asking for the item with id 23...

I hope this makes sense at all >.<... And that someone has some better examples at hand that what I have been able to find.

Comment: Which .net framework and IIS version are you using?

Comment: I am actually not 100% sure, the deployment is somewhat far out so I am figuring that at that time we are talking .NET 4.0 and IIS 7.5.

This is what I have locally atm. But I have issued a support request to the company that is purpose to host this and asked for .NET/OS/IIS version information.

But assume .NET 4.0 and IIS 7.5 for now.

Comment: I have the opportunity for IIS 7 and .NET 4.0 (Windows 2008 server). according to the hosting company.

Comment: @Jens Have you looked at this, ASP.Net Routing with WebForms (not MVC or WCF)    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are your options-

For .net 3.5 sp1 framework with IIS7 you can use asp.net routing feature to have MVC style urls that you mentioned should create a custom route handler implementing IRouteHandler interface as explained here [How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and register your route rules in Application_Start method in Global.asax. For your example you can register a route like this

```
    routes.Add("ItemRoute", new Route
    (
    "item/{itemId}", 
    new CustomRouteHandler("~/item.aspx")
    ));
```

and then you can access itemId in your routed item.aspx page by checking request context item

```
    requestContext.HttpContext.Items["itemId"]
```

For .net framework 4 MVC you dont have to create a custom handler, you can directly use

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("ItemRoute", "item/{itemId}", "~/item.aspx");
```

in you global.asax Application_Start method.

This link explains more about the [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) here is a link to an [MSDN blog, The .Net Endpoint - Using Routes to Compose WCF WebHttp Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/25/using-routes-to-compose-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx) that should get you started.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't quite seem to be what I wan't to achieve, as far as I can see from that series they end up using T4 templates to generate outputs, I really just want to use the ASP.NET renderer or what you may call it.

The rest mostly seem to talk about WCF which is not at all what I want.

Comment: Ok, as it is, this was just a crappy example, Routes does indeed seem to be usefull, a better example was provided by another.

Comment: I have used routing on several WCF projects and find it easy and concise not much to deal with and it works.

Comment: Yes, as my last statement the "blog post" or series of, really is just a crappy example for my case, so it didn't show how to be usefull. The link "How to: Use Routing with Web Forms" posted by another here is on the contrary, so I was just to hasty to judge the concept based on that one example that didn't seem to have anything to do with my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at asp.net/IIS, another option to look at is [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).  It's pretty straight forward to create RESTful services.

Here's a tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233572/Build-truly-RESTful-API-and-website-using-same-ASP

Answer (score 1):

A way of achieve this is using URL rewriting.

If you're planning to host your Web application in Internet Information Services 7.x, you can take advantage of IIS URL Rewriting Module:

- http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

URL rewriting is just mapping a friendly URL to an unfriendly, common one, which is programming-friendly to inspect GET parameters.

For example:

```
http://yourdomain.com/item/48 => http://yourdomain.com/Items.aspx?Id=48
```